# Stub Class for Testing is not being instantiated - Unreal

Tags: c++, unreal

I'm working on a project in Unreal Engine 5.3 where I have a base class UMapViewer derived from UUserWidget. This base class has a method GetAspectRatio(). I have created a derived class MapViewerTestHelper that overrides this method for unit testing. Below I have posted a simple version of the AspectRatio Methods for the base class, the derived class and finally a snippet of calling the derived classes method, it should give me a value of 5.0 but the test returns a value of 10.0

```cpp
UCLASS()
class VORONOIMAP_API UMapViewer : public UUserWidget {
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    explicit UMapViewer(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);
    virtual void NativeConstruct() override;
    virtual float GetAspectRatio() const {
        return 10.0;
    }
}; 

class MapViewerTestHelper : public UMapViewer {
public:
    MapViewerTestHelper(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : UMapViewer(ObjectInitializer) {}
    virtual float GetAspectRatio() const override {
        return 5.0;
    }


It("should correctly calculate the aspect ratio", [this]() {
    MapViewerTestHelper* TestViewer = NewObject<MapViewerTestHelper>();
    const float CalculatedAspectRatio = TestViewer->GetAspectRatio(); 
    TestEqual("This Should retunr 5.0", CalculatedAspectRatio, 5.0);
});
};
```

Comment: Can this be a MSVC bug?

Comment: So that is what I am testing now to see if this is a bug in unreal or MSVC, the current context I am seeing this behavior is with unit testing, I am working on doing a test without testing to see if this behavior is still present. As for it being MSVC these tests are registered and ran in unreal engine itself as an automated test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more debugging, I found that my class that was being instantiated was not the stub class but was rather the base class, this was really weird behavior since I wasn't doing any type of casting, but I found this by doing a simple log in the constructor of the base class and the derived/inherited class, after doing some more research, I came to know about the reflection system in unreal. From what I understand it's how unreal does its memory allocation. My class was built for testing, so I put it in the test file, but unreal does "reflect" in these test files so after I moved my stub class to the same file as my base class it worked fine with no issues. Hopefully this helps somebody else.